# Change elements in list from string to integer, using data imported from CSV

Tags: python, string, csv, int

I'm writing a machine learning program. I gain data from Arduino and send them via serial bus to python for classifier to read. Serial Bus can only transfer "string", while classifier can only process "Integer" (I use KNN classifier)

Here's the problem. The data is stored within lists in csv file.(for example:

['520','521','156','179','191']

['519','521','157','180','189']

I want to change them into int.
The code doesn't appear any problem when compiling. But when I open the csv file again and check the type of it, they still appear to be string but not integer.

The code is like this down below :

```
import csv
with open('sensorFeature.csv', 'r') as sensorRawFile:
    rawData = csv.reader(sensorRawFile)

    with open('new.csv', 'w') as sensorFeatureFile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(sensorFeatureFile)

        for row in rawData:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                row[i] = int(row[i])
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

# checking if I change string to int successfully
with open('new.csv', 'r') as test:
    reader = csv.reader(test)
    for line in reader:
        for x in line:
            print(type(x))
#  the result still tell me they are all string instead of int
```

Comment: I thinl that the problem might be as simple as when you read from a csv file it automatically takes in the data as a string. Wherever you use the data if you just convert the type to an int you should probably be fine.

Comment: oh ja? Is it true? So I should change the data type only when I start to process them?

Comment: Yeah I think that would be the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

csv files are just text files with a certain format, so when you write your data to csv, it's first formatted as text.
You can either:

- Use the data as you aquire it
- Convert the data when you read the csv
- Use pandas.read_csv to easily read the file with the right types
- Use another method of saving the data (i.e. pickling)